# Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received code 502: Bad Gateway

Tags: android, react-native, bintray, jcenter, maven-central

I've been having this issue since about 9 Dec. It seems jcenter has sunset 2 months early (https://status.bintray.com/)

I've updated my RN version to 0.65.0, my Gradle to v6.9 and I've added mavenCentral() in place of jcenter(). Building in offline mode does not work and is not a permanent solution.

This happens during build `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew bundleRelease`

Full error:

```
   > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

root level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21 
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
        supportLibVersion = "30.0.0"
        supportVersion = "30.0.0" 
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { 
            // react-native-date-picker
            url "https://www.jitpack.io"
        }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```